# How do you run `go test` when test files are within a module?

Tags: testing, go

When you have pulled in a module, into your project, how do you run test cases within that module?

i.e. I have done:

```
go get my.repo.com/repo/mymodule
```

And then try to test something in it:

```
server> go test src/my.repo.com/repo/mymodule/my_test.go 
# command-line-arguments
src/my.repo.com/repo/mymodule/article_test.go:4:2: cannot find package "mymodule" in any of:
```

Are we supposed to check out our modules separately and test that way? I can't quite work out what to do. It seems that when I `go run` it knows how to find the module I have fetched, but when I `go test`, it "can't find it" in the path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`go test` expects packages, not folders relative to `$GOPATH`.

So leave out the leading `src/` and the trailing file name, and it'll work:

```
go test my.repo.com/repo/mymodule
```

If the current directory is the package folder you want to test, you can even omit it, e.g.

```
cd $GOPATH/src/my.repo.com/repo/mymodule
go test
```

For reference see [Command go / Test packages](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Test_packages), also run

```
go help test
```