# go test in complex folder structure

Tags: bash, unit-testing, testing, go

I am building a repository of design patterns in golang. To run all tests, I use this bash script. It works.

```
#!/bin/bash
go test creational/abstract_factory/*.go
go test creational/builder/*.go
go test creational/factory/*.go
go test creational/pool/*.go
go test creational/prototype/*.go
go test creational/singleton/*.go
```

It works fine:

```
prompt> ./runtests.sh
ok      command-line-arguments  0.006s
ok      command-line-arguments  0.006s
ok      command-line-arguments  0.006s
ok      command-line-arguments  0.006s
ok      command-line-arguments  0.005s
ok      command-line-arguments  0.006s
```

But, ... If I try to send more directory to `go test` I receive this message "named files must all be in one directory; have creational/pool/ and creational/factory/". This is the reason I've created that bash script.

Is there the possibility to test all folder in one single command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with using the `...`? Change directory to `creational`, then

```
go test ./...
```

This will recurse to all subfolders and execute tests of all packages found. For details, see [Difference in output when calling go test with package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42972827/difference-in-output-when-calling-go-test-with-package/42973175#42973175); and [How do you run `go test` when test files are within a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39012108/how-do-you-run-go-test-when-test-files-are-within-a-module/39012546#39012546)

Note: starting with 1.9, packages in `vendor` subfolders are not matched if `./...` is used. Source: [Go 1.9 Release Notes - Vendor matching with ./...](https://golang.org/doc/go1.9#vendor-dotdotdot). Prior to Go 1.9, `go test ./...` also went into the `vendor` subfolder and ran tests of vendored packages.