# Launch all tests in all packages of a GO app from within VSCode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am pretty new with Golang and I am trying to use it with VSCode as editor.

I have a VSCode workspace which contains the source code of my app divided in several packages, something like

```
myapp (the workspace)
  src
    pck1
      f11.go
      f11_test.go
    pck2
      f21.go
      f21_test.go
```

My objective is to be able to launch all tests with one command from within VSCode. I have installed the GO extension.

In the settings of `myapp-workspace.code-workspace` I have defined

```
  "settings": {
    "go.gopath": "/blah/blah/myapp/",
    "go.testFlags": ["-v"]
  }
```

to make sure that the `GOPATH` points to my workspace folder.

With this setup I am able to run one single test file or one single package from the VSC command palette, but if I try to run command `Go: Test all packages in Workspace` as suggested by @icza, I see on the output window that the command launched is

```
/usr/local/go/bin/go test -timeout 30s ./... -v
```

which results in a series of error messages, the first one being

```
can't load package: package ./pkg/mod/9fans.net/go@v0.0.0-20181112161441-237454027057/acme: cannot use path@version syntax in GOPATH mode
```

If I try from the VSC integrated terminal with `go test` I get the error

```
can't load package: package .: no Go files in /blah/blah/myapp
```

If I try from the the VSC integrated terminal with `go test ./...` I get a long list of errors, similar to the ones generated by the command `Go: Test all packages in Workspace`, and at the end I get the following errors

```
src/game/game.go:4:2: cannot find package "pck1" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/pck1 (from $GOROOT)
        /Users/administrator/go/src/pck1 (from $GOPATH)
src/game/game.go:6:2: cannot find package "pck2" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/pck2 (from $GOROOT)
        /Users/administrator/go/src/pck2 (from $GOPATH)
```

I smell I am doing something wrong around the GOPATH value but I do not know what.

Is there a way to launch all tests in all packages from within VSCode with one command?

Answer (score 1):

There is an integrated command: `Go: Test all packages in Workspace`.

You can also run `go test ./...` in the builtin terminal if you're in the root of your workspace. `./...` will recurse down into all subfolders. See [go test in complex folder structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46263599/go-test-in-complex-folder-structure/46264545#46264545).

Comment: I have tried your suggestions but I am not able to make them work. I have updated my question with some more details.